# Submit form values with jquery works but unable to submit standard html form after success

Tags: jquery

I first want to post some ajax data for a insert in database, this works fine, but submit of standard html form fails with: $("#foo").submit();
The console message loops endless :-/

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// variable to hold request var request; 
// bind to the submit event of our form $("#foo").submit(function(event){
    // abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);
    // let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea, text, hidden");
    // serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/insert_payment_data.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console         
    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    $("#foo").submit();
});

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault(); });

</script>
```

This have been driving me crazy :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's normal :

```
$("#foo").submit();
```

This line at the end of your `request.done` method is triggering the submit of the form, which is probably triggering the AJAX request , which is triggering the `request.done` ... and so on infinitely :-)

What I would do (try) is remove that line, and also remove the `event.preventDefault();` statement you've got at the bottom, so that your submit will simply run as usual after you did your AJAX request.

Comment: Yeh, you don't to submit #foo if you've already posted the form, but if you want to post additional information, then just don't `return false` so that you do your Ajax stuff and **then** post the form as normal.

Comment: The other request is to another domain, thats why i want to use the usual process. What i know of it's not possible to send AJAX request to other domains. How can i break that loop?

Comment: Indeed that's a good reason :-) Please see my updated answer, I think it will solve the problem.

Comment: That helped, now the AJAX request is sent and form submited, but the form values for the regular form is not :-/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the "form is submitted" then "values for the regular form is not" ?

Comment: Both the AJAX and the regular form is submitted, but form data is missing when the regular form is submitted.